# Can't join Azure Active Directory

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, azure, azure-activedirectory

I currently have an issue with Windows 10 Pro and getting it connected to Azure Active Directory.

Microsoft says you need to go to `Settings`→`Accounts`→`Your Info`→`Access Work Or School Connect`. When you press the `+` button it should give you an option to sign in, or, under an `Alternate Actions` text, give you an option to connect to an Active Directory or an Azure Active Directory (see example below). However my options for `Alternate Actions` are invisible.

How it's support to look:

[image: Screenshot of how it's support to look]

How mine looks:

[image: Screenshot of how mine looks]

This computer is already joined to our local domain running on regular active directory. Would this make a difference to adding an account to Microsoft 365/Azure AD?

Comment: “Would this make a difference to adding an account to Microsoft 365/Azure AD?” Why wouldn’t it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have known [how to join your device to Azure AD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/device-management-azuread-joined-devices-setup). In this case, I'd like to explain some things to you.

- For the Alternate Actions, A workstation group PC (non-domain joined computer) can display it.
- If you just want users can access the resources from devices that meet your standards for security and compliance. You can register your device to Azure AD via `+ Connect`.

For the differences between joining and registering devices to Azure AD, you can refer to [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105501-join-windows-10-pc-azure-ad.html).

> Joining a Windows 10 PC to Azure AD means you must sign in to Windows
>   using your Azure AD credentials and is mainly intended to be used on
>   devices which are solely used for work or study purposes and often
>   owned by the employer or school.
>
> Registering a Windows 10 PC on Azure AD means you will continue
>   signing in to Windows with your personal local or Microsoft account,
>   but in addition can access employer / school resources with single
>   sign-on Azure AD credentials. Registering instead of joining is mostly
>   intended to be used when employees / students are allowed to use their
>   own devices for work or studies like in BYOD (Bring Your Own Device)
>   companies and schools, or just to allow employees / students do work /
>   school stuff from home.